# Reactivemongo BSONTimestamp conversion

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I have a record in mongodb having `ts: Timestamp(1437688345, 2)`. When this record is retrieved by reactivemongo in an scala application, it contains `ts: BSONTimestamp(6174824423615365122)`.

In such case, How can I query for all documents which have timestamp greater than `ts: Timestamp(1437688345, 2)` in the database?

Comment: `Timestamp(1437688345, 2)` is the internal representation, with the unique ordinal. Get the time value from it, using `.getTime`, then you can create a meaningful `BSONTimestamp` with.

Comment: @cchantep Agree. However, I wanted to understand how reactivemongo converts `Timestamp(1437688345, 2)` to `BSONTimestamp(6174824423615365122)`.  I have been able to figure out the reverse by doing `6174824423615365122 >>> 32 = 1437688345`